# Map domain name to a space on the server

Tags: forward

I have a domain, e.g., `domain.org` and a hosting space on the server that has the address `http://server/node/myname`.

How I can map `domain.org` to `http://server/node/myname` such that when I visit to `domain.org/some/path` I go to `http://server/node/myname/some/path`?

The domain service offers me web forwarding with HTTP/301 Forwarding or Cloaking Forwarding but none of them works for me. They simply redirect me to `http://server/node/myname` when visiting `domain.org/some/path`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to apache config It would be Directory config within your VirtualHost config part. see https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apache/Virtual_Hosts/

You can write redirects within your site like here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

Answer (score 1):

Modify your .conf file if you have access to Apache configuration like this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://server/node/myname/$1 [P]
```

This will redirect all traffic for the base URL you set above this in that configuration file.

If you already have a rewrite rule in place for domain.org you can use scripting within those pages to do simple URL redirects by parsing the URL on domain.org into a new string for http://server/node/.